# set-acl to AD OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I know that this subject was already discussed here but solutions here and on other sites seem not to work for me.

I want to add to CNO: "CLUSTER" permission on OU to Create Computer Object.

More or less all solution are based on following idea:

```cs
$ou = 'OU=sql,OU=prod,DC=ssd,DC=xxx,DC=net'
$cno = 'CLUSTER1'
$sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier](Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -eq `"$cno`"").SID
$acl = get-acl $ou
$objectGUID = New-Object guid bf967a86-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
$guidNull = New-Object guid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
$ace1 = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid,"ReadProperty,GenericExecute","Allow",$guidNull,"None",$guidNull
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace1)
$ace2 = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid,"CreateChild","Allow",$ObjectGUID,"None",$guidNull
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace2)
set-acl -aclobject $acl $ou
```

I am getting following error:

```
Set-Acl : This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object
At line:1 char:8
+ set-acl <<<<  -aclobject $acl $ou
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (OU=sql,OU=ssd...=xxx,DC=net:String) [Set-Acl], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADProvider:SetSecurityDescriptor:ADError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

Any idea what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error on file systems when using Get-Acl/Set-Acl. Get-Acl retrieves the entire ACL even though you don't want it. You only want the DACL. Set-Acl then attempts to write the entire ACL which fails because Microsoft. Try changing the Get-Acl call to:

```
$acl = (get-acl $ou).Access
```

This should only get you the access rules which you are trying to append to.

**EDIT**

Apologies for the misinformation, on a filesystem this works but AD is "special". The underlying issue is the same, Get-Acl pulls everything and Set-Acl chokes when it attempts to set the owner. Try running the above command in an powershell window run as admin under a domain administrator's context. This may allow you to force past it. Instead I would try using the ADSI accelerator.

```
$ou = 'OU=sql,OU=prod,DC=ssd,DC=xxx,DC=net'
$cno = 'CLUSTER1'
$sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier](Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -eq `"$cno`"").SID
$ouObject = [ADSI]("LDAP://$OU")
$objectGUID = New-Object guid bf967a86-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2
$guidNull = New-Object guid 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
$ace1 = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid,"ReadProperty,GenericExecute","Allow",$guidNull,"None",$guidNull
$ouObject.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($ace1)
$ace2 = new-object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $sid,"CreateChild","Allow",$ObjectGUID,"None",$guidNull
$ouObject.psbase.ObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule($ace2)
$ouObject.psbase.CommitChanges()
```

Another option would be to try working around it with dsacls, you'll need to figure out exactly which [permissions syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771151(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_examples) you want to use though. Please test before running on a live OU.

```
$ou = 'OU=sql,OU=prod,DC=ssd,DC=xxx,DC=net'
$cno = 'CLUSTER1'
$sid = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier](Get-ADComputer -Filter "name -eq `"$cno`"").SID
#should grant the SID Generic Execute, Read Property, Create Children
dsacls $ou /G $sid:GERPCC
```

Comment: But in such case I cannot run $acl.AddAccessRule($ace1)

Comment: Additionally how to execute last line where $acl object is parameter: `set-acl -aclobject $acl $ou`

Comment: I have updated the answer with an ADSI solution that I was able to test and confirm works.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing works. I did first as Administrator and still the same error. ADSI I have tried already and did not work thought different error was returned: `Exception calling "CommitChanges" with "0" argument(s): "A constraint violation occurred.
"
At line:1 char:1
+ $ouObject.psbase.CommitChanges()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Dot
` Last option DSACL most likely works only for users and group not for computer objects. I got following error: `
The parameter /G was not followed by a user/access list`

Comment: This is sounding like a permissions issue. Can you manually assign the permissions via the gui?

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working on any AD object, including DNS records via DN:

```
dsacls $DistinguishedName /G "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:GW"
```